# How to fix the styling of the corners of the border in JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So, I am creating a maze using some algorithm and in this maze I have cells which are basically `div` elements.

Initially all the `cells` have borders but as I proceed through the algorithm, I remove certain borders to achieve the maze. Now the problem is that while doing so, the corners of the borders don't join up properly, which can be seen in the image below.
[image]

Here I have removed the `right` border for `cell[0]` and the `left` border for `cell[1]`,
and removed the `bottom` border for `cell[0]` and the `top` border for `cell[2]`.

I just want to fix the corner of the borders, but I am unable to do so, I would be really thankful to any help.

```js
cells = document.querySelectorAll(".cell");
//Removing the right-left border
cells[0].style["border-right"] = "none";
cells[1].style["border-left"] = "none";
//Removing the top-down border
cells[0].style["border-bottom"] = "none";
cells[2].style["border-top"] = "none";
```

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.row{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.cell{
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-right: 3px solid black;
  border-bottom: 3px solid black;
}

.row .cell:first-of-type{
  border-left: 3px solid black;
}

.row:first-of-type .cell{
  border-top: 3px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="cell first"></div>
      <div class="cell second"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="cell third"></div>
      <div class="cell forth"></div>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Full code:

```js
const nrows = 20;
const ncols = 20;

for (let i=0; i<nrows; i++){
   let row = document.createElement("div");
   row.classList.add("row");
   document.body.appendChild(row);

   for (let j=0; j<ncols; j++){
      let col = document.createElement("div");
      col.classList.add("cell");
      row.appendChild(col);
   }
}


class Cell{
   constructor(i, j){
      this.r = i;
      this.c = j;

      this.neighbors = [];
      this.walls = [true, true, true, true]; //Top Right Bottom Left
      this.visited = false;
   }

   show(){
      if (!this.walls[0]) cellElements[this.r*ncols + this.c].style["border-top"] = "none";
      if (!this.walls[1]) cellElements[this.r*ncols + this.c].style["border-right"] = "none";
      if (!this.walls[2]) cellElements[this.r*ncols + this.c].style["border-bottom"] = "none";
      if (!this.walls[3]) cellElements[this.r*ncols + this.c].style["border-left"] = "none";

      if (this.visited) cellElements[this.r*ncols + this.c].style.background = "greenyellow";
   }

   createNeighbors(){
      if (this.r > 0) this.neighbors.push(grid[(this.r-1)*ncols + this.c]) //Top
      if (this.c < ncols-1) this.neighbors.push(grid[this.r*ncols + (this.c+1)]) //Right
      if (this.r < nrows-1) this.neighbors.push(grid[(this.r+1)*ncols + this.c]) //Bottom
      if (this.c > 0) this.neighbors.push(grid[this.r*ncols + (this.c-1)]) //Left
   }
}


let cellElements = document.querySelectorAll(".cell");

let grid = [];
for (let i=0; i<nrows; i++){
   for (let j=0; j<ncols; j++){
      grid.push(new Cell(i,j));
   }
}
for (let i=0; i<nrows; i++){
   for (let j=0; j<ncols; j++){
      grid[i*ncols + j].createNeighbors();
   }
}

let current = grid[0];
let stack = [];


//Maze Generator Algorithm
function BacktrackingDFS(){
   cellElements[current.r*ncols + current.c].style.background = "darkgreen";
   if (!current.visited){
      current.visited = true;
      stack.push(current);
   }

   let unvisited = [];
   for (let neigh of current.neighbors){
      if (!neigh.visited){
         unvisited.push(neigh);
      }
   }

   if (unvisited.length > 0){
      let randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random()*(unvisited.length));
      let next = unvisited[randomIndex];

      //Remove Walls
      if(current.r - next.r === 1){ //TOP
         current.walls[0] = false;
         next.walls[2] = false;

         //Fixing Corners
         

      }else if(current.c - next.c === -1){ //RIGHT
         current.walls[1] = false;
         next.walls[3] = false;
      }else if(current.r - next.r === -1){ //BOTTOM
         current.walls[2] = false;
         next.walls[0] = false;


         //Fixing Corners


      }else if(current.c - next.c === 1){ //LEFT
         current.walls[3] = false;
         next.walls[1] = false;
      }

      current = next;

   }else if(stack.length > 0){
      current = stack.pop();
   }else{
      console.log("FINISHED!");
      clearInterval(drawLoop);
   }
}




let drawLoop = setInterval(function(){
   for (let i=0; i<nrows; i++){
      for (let j=0; j<ncols; j++){
         grid[i*ncols + j].show();
      }
   }
   BacktrackingDFS();
},100);
```

```css
*{
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
   height: 100vh;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
}

.row{
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
}

.cell{
   height: 20px;
   width: 20px;
   border-bottom: 2px solid black;
   border-right: 2px solid black;
}

.row .cell:first-of-type{
   border-left: 2px solid black;
}

.row:first-of-type .cell{
   border-top: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>Maze Generator</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Have your cells overlap the same amount as your border size.

```js
cells = document.querySelectorAll(".cell");
//Removing the right-left border
cells[0].style["border-right"] = "none";
cells[1].style["border-left"] = "none";
//Removing the top-down border
cells[0].style["border-bottom"] = "none";
cells[2].style["border-top"] = "none";
```

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.row{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.cell{
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin-left: -3px;
  border-right: 3px solid black;
  border-bottom: 3px solid black;
}

.row .cell:first-of-type{
  border-left: 3px solid black;
}

.row:first-of-type .cell{
  border-top: 3px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell first"></div>
        <div class="cell second"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell third"></div>
        <div class="cell forth"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This fix is very specific to this scenario, it doesn't work in my actual code. Here's the link to my actual code: https://codepen.io/ssmkhrj/pen/YzwVmGB
If you are moving everything to the left, then the whole design of my maze gets disturbed, it has somewhere thick and somewhere thin lines. @JerMah

Comment: Your link is 404 @SomShekharMukherjee

Answer (score 1):

Add a filler to fill the gap:

```css
.cell::before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    /*Make sure all values below match your border size and color*/
    left: -3px; bottom: -3px;
    width: 3px; height: 3px;
    border-bottom: 3px solid black;
}
```

Also need to position `.cell` to anchor the filler:

```css
.cell {
    /* ... */
    position: relative;
}
```

#### Added note

In case of your sandbox example, just update this CSS, no need to change HTML or JS:

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.row{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.cell{
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    border-right: 2px solid black;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

.row .cell:first-of-type{
    border-left: 2px solid black;
}

.row:first-of-type .cell{
    border-top: 2px solid black;
}

.cell::before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    /*Make sure all values below match your border size and color*/
    left: -2px; bottom: -2px;
    width: 2px; height: 2px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}
.cell{
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Can you please make your changes [here](https://codepen.io/ssmkhrj/pen/YzwVmGB). I tried adding your changes but it still doesn't fix it. Can you please add it yourself and see. It's a request.

Comment: I did, it works but I can't save cause I dont have account. Just add the css , and change all 3px to 2px

Comment: I have made the changes, but see still the corners aren't perfectly aligned! If possible you can copy that code that makes changes and paste it here.

Comment: I changed filler from background to border and it looks ok to me. added to answer

Comment: I added height: 2.5px and it worked for me, but I can't understand why? It would be really nice if you could help me!

Comment: it may be because background mode of the filler mismatch with border. I switched to border and it works fine  without changing the height. Look at my updated answer. Your change is a hack and may not work again when you change your layout or css

Comment: Ya, now it works Perfectly, THANKS a lot for your time and effort. Also, can you suggest me some good resource to read about `fillers` and what exactly is happening here. I am new to CSS and I am unable to understand this.

Comment: But there's still a problem, it does work on Codepen, but it doesn't work in Chrome. Help!

Comment: I did bring your code to Chrome and fix the problem there not on codepen. Make sure you copy everything right

Comment: No, it doesn't work for me, please check once again!

Comment: Is the CSS, HTML and JS that you are running in Chrome exactly the same as you posted on Codepen?

Comment: Just added the HTML boilerplate because Codepen needs no HTML, it just needs the contents inside the `<body>`

Comment: I did the same. Check [screenshot of my Chrome](https://pasteboard.co/JeAnQde.png). What problem did you see?

Comment: Can you please paste your code here, I can't figure what's causing this problem.

Comment: Too long to paste here. Download this [CSS file](https://tmpfiles.org/dl/56879/index.css) and make sure you import it in your HTML file

Comment: Modify your answer, and paste the Code in your answer, like others have done.

Comment: You got it there

Answer (score 0):

I added a pseudo element to the cell that didn't had the border. Does this help you ?

```js
cells = document.querySelectorAll(".cell");
//Removing the right-left border
cells[0].style["border-right"] = "none";
cells[1].style["border-left"] = "none";
//Removing the top-down border
cells[0].style["border-bottom"] = "none";
cells[2].style["border-top"] = "none";
```

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.row{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.cell{
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-right: 3px solid black;
  border-bottom: 3px solid black;
}

.row .cell:first-of-type{
  border-left: 3px solid black;
}

.row:first-of-type .cell{
  border-top: 3px solid black;
}

.cell.forth {
  position: relative;
}
.cell.forth::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -3px; left: -3px;
  width: 3px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell first"></div>
        <div class="cell second"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell third"></div>
        <div class="cell forth"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This might be helpful, but the problem with this is, you are using the forth cell which I won't have access to in my actual algorithm in runtime, I want a fix that uses only the cells for which the borders are being changed. I hope you're getting my point.

Comment: You can add a class with Javascript and do the width/height of the cell + border and then moving from the pixels of border (3px here) negatively to fix. Would that help you ?

Comment: [Here's](https://codepen.io/ssmkhrj/pen/YzwVmGB) my complete code, can you please insert your fix here, it would be really helpful.

Answer (score -1):

So, finally after scratching my head for almost 10 hours I got the fix.

> Changes in CSS

```
.bottomRightCorner::before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    right: 0; bottom: 0;
    width: 2px; height: 2px;
    background: black;
}
.cell{
    position: relative;
}
```

Adding a method named `fix` in the `Cell` class, and every time while calling `.show()`, also calling `.fix()`.

> Changes in `Cell` Class

```
fix(){
        if (!this.walls[1] && !this.walls[2]) cellElements[this.r*ncols + this.c].classList.add("bottomRightCorner");
    }
```

> Changes in `drawLoop`

```
let drawLoop = setInterval(function(){
    for (let i=0; i<nrows; i++){
        for (let j=0; j<ncols; j++){
            grid[i*ncols + j].show();
        }
    }
    for (let i=0; i<nrows; i++){
        for (let j=0; j<ncols; j++){
            grid[i*ncols + j].fix();
        }
    }
    BacktrackingDFS();
},100);
```